# avoid Typescript complaint on missing React component props

Tags: typescript

Using typescript checker only with VSCode on a javascript React project with a `jsconfig.json` I will need `disable/bypass` some typescript checks like `missing property` on objects and omited `props`.

for Example:

```js
const Comp = ({ color, center, dark }) => <div> /* real code here */ </div>


<Comp color="blue" />   // TS check complaint on missing property: ts 2739
```

I would like to be able to use some TS check and `disable` others.

I try, without luck:

```
// global.d.ts
declare global {
  namespace JSX {
    type Element = string;
    interface ElementAttributesProperty {
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: It's [not possible](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/11051) to disable certain messages. Why do you want to do this? Is it because `center` and `dark` are optional? Or are you in a hurry and you don't want to write types? (In the latter case, perhaps you could write a `.jsx` file instead of a `.tsx` file.) Another option is to use `//@ts-ignore`

Comment: I just want to use only certains features of typescript on the editor  and avoid write some types, specially React related. My files are `.js`

Answer (score 1):

If you really want to avoid writing types for those properties, then you could use `any`:

```
const Comp = ({ color, center, dark }: any) => <div> /* real code here */ </div>
```

You will of course need to disable the `no-any` rule, assuming you have that enabled (you should).  You can disable it for the entire file by putting this earlier in the file:

```
/* tslint:disable:no-any */
```

Of course, doing this will lose the ability for TypeScript to warn you when you are passing the wrong properties!  But at least it will make it clear where the missing types are, and you can always go over later and clean up.

In our team, we discourage people from using `any` and instead encourage them to get used to writing types for everything.  This did slow us down at first, but it didn't take long for us to get used to doing it.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you haven't specified the signature of your component's props. You could solve this by declaring an interface

```
interface CompProps {
  color: string;
  center: boolean; // or whatever its type is
  dark: boolean;
}

const Comp = ({ color, center, dark }: CompProps) => <div>{/* real code here */}</div>
```

Comment: I'm trying to avoid write React related types. I will like to add some `ambient` JSX declaration in order to avoid specified Components type declarations.